# Filtering ClassDeclarationSyntax inheriting from generic type

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I'm writing a source generator that adds code to partial types inheriting from a specific generic type (that is also generated). I'm using `IIncrementalGenerator` and I'm struggling with the predicate for `CreateSyntaxProvider`

What's working so far is emitting the base type:

```cs
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
    string source = $@"// <auto-generated/>
using System;

namespace Partialzzz
{{
    public class Partialzzz<T> where T : class
    {{
        public void Hello() => Console.WriteLine($""{{typeof (T)}}"");
    }}
}}
";

    context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput(ctx =>
        ctx.AddSource("Partialzzz.g.cs", SourceText.From(source, Encoding.UTF8))
    );

    // Filter all Partialzzz<T> subclasses
    IncrementalValuesProvider<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classDeclarations = context.SyntaxProvider
        .CreateSyntaxProvider(
            predicate: IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration,
            transform: Transform
        )!;

    // Combine the selected classes with the Compilation
    IncrementalValueProvider<(Compilation, ImmutableArray<ClassDeclarationSyntax>)> compilationAndClasses
        = context.CompilationProvider.Combine(classDeclarations.Collect());

    // Generate the source using the compilation and classes
    context.RegisterSourceOutput(compilationAndClasses,
        static (spc, source) => Execute(spc, source.Item1, source.Item2));
}
```

In `IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration`, I need to select all (partial) subclasses of `Partialzzz<T>`:

```cs
private static bool IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration(SyntaxNode s, CancellationToken _) =>
    s is ClassDeclarationSyntax c
    && c.Modifiers.Any(m => m.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
    && c.BaseList?.Types.FirstOrDefault()?.Type.ToString().Contains("Partialzzz") == true;
```

Selecting only classes that have the partial modifier works, but the way I select subclasses of `Partialzzz<T>` is ugly and not specific enough.

I'd like to able to write something like `partial class Foo : Partialzzz<Bar> { }` where the `Hello()` method gets added, and some other code based on `Bar`.

The end goal is to create an implementation of Typescript's `Partial<T>` type.